# In my Netbeans Desktop Application.......its Desktop icon image is not getting changed?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a Desktop Application in Netbeans using JAVA. I want to change its icon image(i.e. icon image other then the default JAVA cup). For this i have used the following lines of code..

```
        URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("qrg/resources/qrgicon.png");
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image img = kit.createImage(url);
        this.getFrame().setIconImage(img);
```

in try and catch and getting NO error in program.
But on using this code, the icon image is ONLY changing on the application titlebar, when i am opening the application. The image icon is NOT changing at the desktop icon of applicatiojn, which is used(or clicked) to open the application. So please tell me what can i do to change the image of its desktop icon ???

Comment: And you think that the path is ok?

Comment: Try with `frame.setIconImage( new ImageIcon("path").getImage() )`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java cannot change the icon used to launch the application. This is because that icon is managed by the operating system, not Java. On Windows, the "Java Cup" icon is associated with the .JAR extension and is not managed by individual applications.

Answer (score 1):

I created a separate shortcut to run my Java jar. I was then able to change the icon *of the shortcut* to be whatever I wanted. I don't know if that satisfies your requirements, but it worked for mine.

[image]